# difference between drain, release,dealloc and retain in Objective-C/

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Hi i want to know the difference between drain, release,dealloc and retain in Objective-C.

Answer (score 23):

- `retain` increase the reference count on an object
- `release` decreases the reference on an object
- `drain` is used in place of release on **ONLY** for NSAutoreleasePool objects due to some arcana related to the Objective C garbage collection
- `dealloc` is called by the system once the retainCount of an object hits 0. It is where you clean up various things your object has (like a deconstructor or finalizer). You should **NEVER** call it directly, except for calling `[super dealloc]` at the end of your `dealloc` routines.

You really should just read through Apple's memory management [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: -drain is useful on NSAutoreleasePool so that it functions under GC as well. Namely, it triggers a collection immediately. If we used -release, then under GC, that message would be ignored, and nothing would happen.